# Error running Chimp / Webdriver.io / Selenium on Fargate (Chrome failed to start)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chimp.js, aws-fargate

I'm trying to run my test cases on Fargate using Chimp, which internally uses Webdriver.io / Selenium.  They run just fine in my docker container when I'm running them on my EC2 instance, but as soon as I upload my container to ECS and try to execute the same test using Fargate, I get the following error:

```
Chimp version:  0.50.2
ChromeDriver version:  ChromeDriver 2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c)
Java version:  openjdk version "1.8.0_151", OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-1~deb9u1-b12), OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
Selenium version:  3.8.1
Selenium drivers version:  chrome: 2.34, ie: 2.50.0, firefox: 0.19.1
OS version:  Linux 4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64
Node version:  v6.11.5
Browser version:  chrome undefined
[33m
[chimp] Running...[39m
[chimp][helper] setupBrowserAndDDP had error
{ Error: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
    at initBrowser (node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/chimp-helper.js:189:43)
    at Object.setupBrowserAndDDP (node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/chimp-helper.js:264:7)
    at node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/cucumberjs/hooks.js:22:24
    at node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c),platform=Linux 4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64)
    at new RuntimeError (node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/ErrorHandler.js:144:12)
    at Request._callback (node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/RequestHandler.js:313:39)
    at Request.self.callback (node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
  details: undefined,
  message: 'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c),platform=Linux 4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64)',
  type: 'RuntimeError',
  seleniumStack: 
   { type: 'UnknownError',
     message: 'An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.',
     orgStatusMessage: 'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c),platform=Linux 4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64)' } }
Error: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
    at initBrowser (node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/chimp-helper.js:189:43)
    at Object.setupBrowserAndDDP (node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/chimp-helper.js:264:7)
    at node_modules/chimp/dist/lib/cucumberjs/hooks.js:22:24
    at node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:43:40
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522913 (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c),platform=Linux 4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64)
    at new RuntimeError (node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/ErrorHandler.js:144:12)
    at Request._callback (node_modules/webdriverio/build/lib/utils/RequestHandler.js:313:39)
    at Request.self.callback (node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at node_modules/continuation-local-storage/node_modules/async-listener/glue.js:188:31
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
Cucumber steps failed
```

I've tried adding the following lines to the start of my test script to make sure Chrome is there and responding:

```
echo Running chrome version:
google-chrome --version
```

And the result is:

```
Running chrome version:
Google Chrome 62.0.3202.75
```

So Chrome is there and responding.  Why won't it work in Fargate?

The following debug line from the Chimp debug info at the start looks like the biggest culprit:

```
Browser version:  chrome undefined
```

I have no idea why it can't find it.  It reports the correct version when I'm running locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long time later I learned that my docker container hadn't successfully finished all of it's operations before I was saving the image.  When I fixed that, this problem went away.  X11 runs fine in a Docker container / AWS Fargate.

Comment: This ended up sucking for me because Chrome headless (actually Selenium / Webdriver.io under Chrome headless) doesn't easily support downloading files.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try Xvfb for the framebuffer without Headless Chrome, in the event --headless mode doesn't work with your application (which seems to be a somewhat frequent event).

Comment: Well, you were correct that `--headless` was a huge mistake.  I ended up starting my process with: `xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args=\"-screen 0 1080x1080x24\" bash -c \"myTask.sh\"`.  Replace `myTask.sh` with whatever you're trying to run.